# Getting data from DataGridView and exporting to database

Tags: c#, oledb

I cannot get my desired data from a `DataGridView`. It only exports the first row of data.

Database:

```
 acct_no | first_name | last_name  |  mid_name   
-----------------------------------------------------------
  201    | first1     | last1      |  mid1
  202    | first2     | last2      |  mid2
  203    | first3     | last3      |  mid2
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I run my code the result is:

```
 acct_no | first_name | last_name  |  mid_name   
-----------------------------------------------------------
  201    | first1     | last1      |  mid1
  202    | first1     | last1      |  mid2
  203    | first1     | last1      |  mid2
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

It didn't loop to all rows. Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    foreach (var cell in dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells)
    { 
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MEMBER (ACCT_NO, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MID_NAME) VALUES(@ACCT_NO, @LAST_NAME, @FIRST_NAME, @MID_NAME)";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACCT_NO", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LAST_NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRST_NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MID_NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see what's the problem in you example. All the rows seem to be here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** As I can not see your `ExecuteNonQuery()` statement in the loop, I suspect that you are executing the query at the end of the loop.

**EDIT 1:** As @AbZy suggested from comments your `foreach` loop does not make any sense because you are adding all `cell` values  from the current `row`.
So remove your `foreach` loop.

Assuming you are are using OleDb, I don't think `OleDb` supports `Named Parameters`. So instead of parameter names provide the question marks in your query.

**Solution1:** Execute the `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` statement inside the loop and clear the parameters.

Just add following two statements to your code:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Parameters.Clear();
```

**Complete Code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RP_CMG01 (ACCT_NO, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, 
                MID_NAME) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACCT_NO", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LAST_NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRST_NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MID_NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 command.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

Comment: You should also point out that `foreach (var cell in dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells)` doesn't make sense here, it should be removed

Comment: @AbZy: Thanks dear :) , i have made changes

Comment: AbZy and @Sudhakar , thank you very much. it seems working good. just one question. after completed task a exception message appear : PARAMETER ACCT_no HAS NO DEFAULT VALUE

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi sir what causes "overflow" oledb exception?

Comment: @rein: did you check my editted answer, `OleDb` does not support named parameters.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi i found whats causes my overflow exception. just some code i forgot to change. yup i tried your answer. so far my app runs smoothly. thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            foreach (var cell in dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells)
            { 
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RP_CMG01 (ACCT_NO, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MID_NAME) VALUES(@ACCT_NO, @LAST_NAME, @FIRST_NAME, @MID_NAME)";

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACCT_NO", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LAST_NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRST_NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MID_NAME", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

                command.ExecuteNoQuery();
                command.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        }
```